# How do you import a custom lambda function in Amplify React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

**CURRENTLY**

I have created an amplify app with react, and have a component `src > components > MyReactComponent.js` with a button that when pressed I would like to get data from an external API (that requires auth), and retrieve back to the react component.

The workflow I was building is as follows:

[image]

I created a Lambda function in Amplify CLI using `amplify add function`. This created a function `getExternalData` in my project structure as follows:

```
-- amplify
| -- backend
|   -- api/
|   -- auth/
|   -- function
|     -- getExternalData   <--- newly created function
|       -- dist/
|       -- src
|       | -- event.json
|       | -- index.js
|       | -- package-lock.json
|       | -- package.json
|       -- getExternalData-cloudformation-template.json
-- src
  -- components
  | -- MyReactComponent.js
  -- graphql
    -- mutations.js
    -- queries.js
    -- subscriptions.js
    -- schema.json
```

**ISSUE**

How do I import this function into `MyReactComponent.js`?

The dirtiest but most direct (and incorrect) method I could think of was:

`import { getExternalData } from "../../amplify/backend/function/getExternalData/getExternalData";`

But this returned the error:

`Module not found: You attempted to import ../../amplify/backend/function/getExternalData/getExternalDatawhich falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

I feel like ideally I would want the function to be available under `graphql` folder, but not sure how to automate it being listed there.

**REQUEST**

Any help to either:

1. Help me import the Lambda function into `MyReactComponent.js`, or
2. Suggest a better solution for securely getting the external data into react,

would be greatly appreciated :)